# Angular 14: Calling GET or POST always return null response

Tags: angular

I have AuthService which has login() method like:

```
private authUrl = "http://localhost:8080/myapi/auth";
 
login(username: string, password: string) {

     let options = {
       headers: new HttpHeaders()
         .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
         .append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password))
     };
    
    return this.http.get(`${this.authUrl}`, options);

}
```

I have component making a call to this service like:

```
login() {

  this.authService.login(uid, pwd).subscribe(resp => {
      console.log("received resp : " + resp ); //ALWAYS NULL ???
    },
    error => {
      console.log("got error: " + error);  
    },
    () => {
      console.log("successfully completed call");
    }
  );
  
}
```

The `login()` method shows its response in browser dev tools Network tab as **200 OK**.  I also see my custom headers being returned.

So, there is no errors as expected.  However, the returned `resp` is always null, so the output on the console is always

```
received resp: null
successfully completed call
```

Why is `resp` returned in response always null?

Comment: If there is no body, this is expected? If you want more, add {observe: ‘response’}

Comment: Inside your options

Comment: Sorry, that makes no difference, the response `data` is still null.  Again, I have no errors,I get 200OK and my custom headers but `data` is always null so I cannot check status or get my custom headers on it

Comment: No errors in your network console?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have some authentication service with:

login(uname: string, pass: string) {

```
return this.http.post<any>(`${this.authUrl}`, {"uname": uname, "pass": pass},
  {
    headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    , observe: 'response'
  })
  .pipe(tap(res => {
    if (res.ok) {
      // you are authenticated
    }
  }))
```

}

, then call it from your controller:

```
  login() {
    this.authorizationService.login(this.loginForm.value.uname, this.loginForm.value.pass)
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          // you are authenticated
        }
      },
      error => {
        // you got error
      },
      () => {
        // you completed call successfully, then this callback is called
      });
  }
```